# Error 502.5 - Process Failure plus an error in event log

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I created a new VS 2015 update 3 project and named it ng2starterapp using the [ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 template](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio).
I have ASP.NET Core SDK installed version 1.1.0-SDK-1.0.0 Preview 2.1-003177 (x64).

When I run the app I get a web page with error "**HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure**..".

**The event log has this error**:

> Failed to start process with commandline '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" -p "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -a "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ng2starterapp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\ng2starterapp.dll" -wd "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ng2starterapp" -wbe Global\Buildd4b3566c-2166-4146-a843-6a2f6b44589f -lse Global\Launchc60b8fcf-8748-4152-956c-39ef27afd64d', ErrorCode = '0x80004005'.

Any ideas why I get this error?

Comment: If you run this from the console (`dotnet run`), does it work?